# LyX / LaTeX Numeric Referencing question

Tags: lyx, citing

I am writing a paper using numeric referencing. Say I have a list of references like so:

```
... as presented in [3], [4], [5]
```

How do I instruct LyX or LaTeX to typeset it as:

```
... as presented in [3] - [5]
```

I have seen this done in several papers. Obviously I could do this manually, but I wouldn't want to do that, as references tend to get messed up very quickly.

Comment: Does adding `\usepackage{cite}` to the LaTeX preamble work?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Can you you post the answer so that I can mark it as correct answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the features of the `cite` package is that it automatically compresses ranges of citations, so go to Document --> Settings --> LaTeX preamble and add

```
\usepackage{cite}
```